# adding objects to household database

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add a custom item to the household objects database and am trying to follow the suggestions made here:

[post](http://answers.ros.org/question/9619/how-to-add-objects-to-a-local-household-database#15205)

my question is about using insert_model.cpp as suggested in the comments.

it seems to read the model data fine, but then tries to copy to one of Matei's directories... "/u/matei/data/household_objects/"

Anyone know how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31115/adding-objects-to-household-database/) by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that in the database there is a table called "variable" which has a key called "MODEL_ROOT" with the value "/u/matei/data/household_objects/".
I'm using pgmin3 to edit it and here you have screenshot i.imgur.com/mP0qZUo.png

(Before getting to this error I needed to change in insert_model.cpp the line:

```
  household_objects_database::ObjectsDatabase database("**localhost**", "5432", "willow", "willow", "household_objects");
```

---

Originally posted by [awesomebytes](https://answers.ros.org/users/4672/awesomebytes/) with karma: 66 on 2013-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2013-04-17**:
Yup - that is the right place!